Issues with LT4363 Surge Stopper: OV Pin
My question is regarding the high voltage surge stopper LT4363-2
Here is my simulation:

My question is about the OV pin. The simulation is designed to turn off around VIN=79.9V, but it does not! It does not consider the input voltage, and as long as it is higher than the clamp voltage (71.4V) in our design, when Vtmr reaches 1.275V, it turns off. So, if I set the input to 140V for 4s, it does not turn off abruptly. I cannot understand the purpose of the OV pin here.



It might have something to do with your 7 MOSFETs in parallel having more than 12x the gate charge of the MOSFET in the "typical application" circuit.  What are the traces on your graphs?  How are they referenced?

@vir
Thank you. I changed the FETs to ones with a smaller Qg, it fixed the issue. However, when I changed the input peak voltage from 100V to 70V, I saw the drop and the issue in Vout following the input voltage again. Any idea why it happens?

@chami Can you ask some specific questions, its not easy to discern where you are having trouble.

Isn't this doing exactly as described in the datasheet?

"OV: [...] When OV is above its threshold of 1.275V, the fault retry function is inhibited even when the TMR pin voltage has reached its retry threshold."  || "TMR: [...] When TMR reaches 1.275V, the FLT pin pulls low to indicate the detection of a fault condition. If the condition persists, the pass transistor turns off when TMR reaches the threshold of 1.375V."

@MrGerber: I see your point. The datasheet has a very vague sentence: "It regulates the output during an overvoltage event by controlling the gate of an external N-channel MOSFET." But it does not make sense, as the CLAMP voltage defined by FB is supposed to regulate the voltage. What this pin does still does not make sense to me. Even if I connect OV to ground and disable it, I get the same result.

Yes of course - It's not the OV pin that disables the pass transistor, it's the TMR pin. The OV pin just disables the retry-function on the TMR pin.

If you want to shorten the time before shutdown, you need to decrease the value of C2

@MrGerber: Thank you so much. I see the effect of C2 in the simulation. So, you mean if I want the output voltage to be clamped at V1, I need to select OV close to V1? This way, I will disable the retry function on the TMR pin, and the circuit will remain undamaged. Is this what OV is supposed to do?

I think there is a misunderstanding about how this chip is supposed to function, maybe? It is not supposed to disconnect quickly on overvoltage events, quite the opposite - it's supposed to clamp overvoltages to /allow normal operation/ during short overvoltages. Only on persistent overvoltage conditions is it supposed to turn off. See page 11 application information in the datasheet

@MrGerber: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Understood. I will try to read more about the retry functionality, but you answered my question. Thanks.

It's a surge stopper, not a cutoff (purely), nor just a regulator.  They have integrated several nice-to-have features into one controller.
In short, it's doing precisely what it's supposed to do.  When voltage exceeds threshold, output is regulated (voltage limiting).  The load remains active for some time.  How long, depends on the timer capacitor, and load current.  Load current is SNSed, and a proportional current is applied to the timer capacitor to hasten turn-off.  This roughly models the power dissipation of the pass transistor, allowing its SOA to be more fully utilized.  (In fact, there is a product term due to V(VCC, OUT) to make this even more accurate, assuming VCC isn't limited -- if your VIN is within limits, I would encourage direct connection, otherwise, set as high of a limit as possible, i.e. zener voltage near chip ratings.)
There is also a current limiting function, where V(SNS, OUT) is regulated; this is considered a fault condition (e.g. perhaps the load has failed shorted so it's not dropping much voltage anymore, putting the full drop across the pass transistor) and a multiplied current flows into the timer capacitor.
If turn-off threshold has not been reached, the timer capacitor voltage relaxes slowly over time (a small discharge current), mimicking transient thermal resistance of the pass transistor.  If threshold is crossed, output is disabled, and either remains off until several cycles of the timer capacitor (auto restart version), or latches off until reset or power cycle (manual version).
Your simulation shows a voltage limit without current limit, and a corresponding charge of the timer capacitor, then reaching turn-off threshold and remaining disabled for some time.  Note that vtmr does not begin rising until VIN jumps up above OV threshold.
This is more or less rephrasing remembered from the application section of the datasheet; consult it for greater detail.

@ Tim Williams: Thank you. You mentioned: "Note that Vtmr does not begin rising until VIN jumps up above the OV threshold." In the simulation, Vtmr starts rising when VIN jumps above the limit voltage. If I choose OV to be very high, like 200V, the Vtmr plot does not differ.

Also, if the threshold is crossed and the output is disabled, why does Vtmr still continue to increase? Why is there no decrease or cool-off in Vtmr in the simulation? Thank you.

Sorry, not OV pin, when output regulation is active. For vtmr behavior, see datasheet page 12. It's charged up to an internal threshold, then discharged to a lower threshold, at a low current, giving a generous delay before attempting restart.
